# Cron job fails while executing python script - keyError

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

**My cron job:**

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /path/to/python/script.py >> /path/to/my/log.txt 2>&1
```

each time this job runs it generates this error in my `log.txt`:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    62  100    62    0     0     40      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    40
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/python/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    token = get_token(user)
  File "/path/to/python/script.py", line 14, in get_token(user)
    return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['path/to/my/login.sh', 'PROD', 'my-tokenservice', user]))['myToken']
KeyError: 'myToken'
```

**script.py:**

```
user ='username'


def get_token(user):
    return json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['path/to/my/login.sh', 'PROD', 'my-tokenservice', user]))['myToken']

token = get_token(user)
```

...

when running script outside cron in python idle it works perfectly fine. Would someone know how this can be fixed? thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to find out what `subprocess.check_output` is actually returning. Is your path to the subprocess really relative?

Comment: do the subprocess call, json loads and indexing on separate lines. Log the results or use pdb to find the error? I don't think you have enough info in this question for someone to find the problem as it seems like `login.sh` is returing json without the field you want.

Comment: Also why run it outside in idle, why not run it outside of cron the same way you're running it in cron i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /path/to/python/script.py`? Then you can more easily use pdb

Comment: @jordanm, it's a made up path in this example here. When I run the actual one directly in python3.x it works perfectly and returns value for 'myToken' correctly and script is executed without errors. It only throws keyError when running this script as cron job. Would there be anything about permissions maybe? As I'm asking for output using separate `login.sh`? However I made sure that login.sh has permissions set to 777 and is in the same folder as `script.py`.  I'm pretty confident to say that this issue is related to cron env as script throws no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dan as above. My code works in python3.x either when running it directly in python or as  `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /path/to/python/script.py` in terminal. Only in cron it throws keyError. It seems like  `login.sh` might not be properly recognized inside my script in cron. Not sure how to run pdb on cron job for this example as I freshly started my journey in python. Would you be able to help further or give me instructions how could I provide you with more information to the above? thanks!

Comment: @Baobab1988 specify the absolute path to login.sh, not a relative one

Comment: just add the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to where you want a break point, I'm fairly sure that even in a cronjob it will stop and give you an interactive python repl. You might need cron to be running in the foreground though. I'm not sure. But also logging will help you find errors too. Maybe try [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) for example.