# Applescript to close terminal after script is executed

Tags: cron, applescript

I'm using AppleScript as my Cron job and it opens terminal + executes a script.

```
*/1 * * * * osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python path/to/my/script.py"'
```

Would there be a way to add to this a bit that will close Terminal window once script is fully executed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why are using osascript/Applescript to run your `.py` script ? You can invoke the `.py`  file without the use of AppleScript, thus negating any need to close a Terminal window - see answer  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799023/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-to-run-every-10-minutes#answer-799024)

Comment: @RobC I'm struggling to set this up as cron for python script directly see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641267/cron-job-fails-while-executing-python-script-keyerror?noredirect=1#comment109044812_61641267

Comment: You don't need `osascript` here, nor do you need `python`. Just put the proper full path (with leading slash which is currently omitted) to your script and ensure your script has a proper shebang and is executable. You are making life difficult for yourself.